# APEX Data Load Wizard - concatenate 2 .csv columns into 1 database column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Is it possible to concatenate two .csv columns into one database column through Data Load Wizard in oracle APEX?

e.g.
I have firstName and lastName in .csv file and want to concanate and insert it in ename database column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a recurring process and you cannot change the way the data is coming through, here's a simple approach:

Have all three columns in the table.

- FirstName
- LastName
- Ename

Use the wizard to populate values into FirstName and LastName columns and have an after insert trigger that would concatenate the values of those two columns and update it to Ename.

Only use Ename on the forms, reports in the application and do not display FirstName, LastName to the outside world, just use them to populate Ename.

Comment: Just found out there is a way to do it via APEX. In "Data Load Definition Details -> Column Names Aliases"  you can add "Multiple Spreadsheet Columns " and populate firstName and lastName into those "temp" columns. Next just create new Tranformation rule on Ename and concanate firstName and lastName.But I will use the trigger option anyway.